# How to execute a function only at start? Facebook PHP-SDK

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, session, sdk

i have created a facebook app, it's a site based on PHP and some mySQL functions.

There is a mysql function that consumes a lot of time, and i want that this function is only executed at the beginning of the session after the user is logged in.

My suboptimal solution at the moment is, that after the user starts my app, i check in the sql database if he has already started the app today and if so, then i skip the time-consuming function (it would be better if i check it every time where the user starts the app)

(if date()>datelastlogin then do something...)

Do you have any other elegant ideas?

Edit: 
the solution with if ($_SESSION['firstLogon'] = true) doesnt also work:

here is my code:

```
    <?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.php");
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/facebook_config.php");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/script/facebook.php");
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/connection.php");




function friends($userid){
    global $dbcon;
    //that is the time consuming function
    $query=.....

}

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user_id) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');



                if (!isset($_SESSION['firstLogon']))

                {
                echo "firstlogon";
                friends($user_id);
                }

        } 
         catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {


      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    } 


?>
```

Comment: I updated it, see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is using the $_SESSION not an option? I would flag a session variable as such:

```
$_SESSION['firstLogon'] = true;
```

Then you can check that variable every time you run it. When it's not set (or not equal to true) then you could run your mysql calls.

This way you require no extra DB activity, you just check the session variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, that would be perfect solution. I tested it, but unfortunately it didn't work. Still executes everytime if script runs.  See above for code details.

Comment: Ahh but you're not using session correctly- I erroneously assumed you'd know how to do that. You have to start the session calling session_start() first, and at the top of the page you need to check for the firstLogon varible each time. 
Look here: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: Ok i solved it, see above. I changed the if-condition to: if (!isset($_SESSION['firstLogon'])) P.S.: session_start() doesn't work with facebook PHP SDK because the SDK starts automatically the session for you :) BIG THANKS!